# Allow angular-ui-accordion to collapse on body click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion, angular-ui

I have a angular-ui-accordion(panel) on the left side of my page. The functionality is working fine.

But I got an Issue where the accordion only collapses when clicked at the `ui-accordion-header`. My requirement is to make my accordion to collapse when clicked anywhere on the panel. Does anyone know of a workaround to achieve this?

Im stuck at this point. Help

Comment: Please show the code... Will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `uib-accordion-group` directive has a `is-open` attribute that watches upon an expression, if the expression evaluates to false, that specific accordion-panel will close, you can take a model value, give it to `is-open` and change it via an event (i.e. `ng-click` etc..).

Here's a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/UeJ1iqgnH9x9oNkP5tTO?p=preview)

Comment: bro my  accordion is working fine. i just what my collapse  when clicked anywhere on the panel. now it accordion collapse only when clicked at the  ui-accordion header

Comment: attach an `ng-click` on that panel

Comment: i have one function already ..but how can i use ng-click to collapse

Comment: use `is-open="exp"` and `exp = false` to collapse

Comment: can you make a plunk with all your accordion code ?

Comment: bro .. my accordion is collapsing correctly .i problem is i have a accordion header which is a panel. if i click the accordion header it will collapse. but if i click any where else it wont collapse .i tried with is-open its opening all the accordion body. im using ng-repeat . you can see the codes

Comment: you mean, something like this ? https://plnkr.co/edit/UeJ1iqgnH9x9oNkP5tTO?p=preview

Comment: bro you see if we click only at the accordion  header it collapase.i want it to collapse if we click anywhere on the panel

Comment: here what happens is you have to specifically click the heading text

Comment: the uib-accordion panel don't expose the panel body element, but rather will transclude anything you put on the body panel, so the best you can do is to define a container element (div) and give it the ng-click.

Comment: do you have a demo plunker

Comment: the updated plunk, is enough. but you may want to tweak some css so the `div` will fill the entire body panel